# Initializing FileStream and StreamWriter fields in a service class

Tags: c#, static

I made this code outside the methods because I need to close and dispose the streamwriter and filestream in the OnStop() method:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
private StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
//The fs is in red line, having error
```

However, the fs inside the new StreamWriter prompts the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property..". So I made the FileStream static:

```
private static FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

When I ran the program, it doesn't write to the textfile and concluded that it's because of the static. I searched about it and read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): "A class can be declared static, indicating that it contains only static members. It is not possible to create instances of a static class using the new keyword. Static classes are loaded automatically by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program or namespace containing the class is loaded."

This is my sample code:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    private StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
//The fs is in red line, having error. Look in my description for error's details
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WriteText);
        timer.Interval = 5000; //5 seconds
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void WriteText(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Windows Service");
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

What do you think should I do?

Comment: No need for `static`. Initialize them in constructor.

Comment: Can you post up the full class so we can diagnose better ?

Comment: You could try wrapping in a non static class

Comment: What exactly is your question? and please show us you onStop() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done should work fine, but it's not a good way to do it, so it's not worth investigating why it's not working. Having static variables in a class doesn't make the class static.

Just declare the variables without initialisers, then set the variables when you want to open the file:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer;
    private FileStream fs;
    private StreamWriter sw

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WriteText);
        timer.Interval = 5000; //5 seconds
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void WriteText(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Windows Service");
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Stop(); // Stop the timer before closing the file
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!Thank you very much! At first, I tried initializing it in OnStart but still didn't work. Then I noticed that you moved the timer.stop on top and it worked! I should take note on that, always stop the timer before closing files.. Thanks!

Comment: @Guffa Why are you invoking sw.Close() and sw.Dispose() ? It was my understanding that sw.Close() is also responsible for calling the dispose method in the TextWriter. Or am I confusing things here?

Comment: @DSF: You are correct that both calls are not needed. I left that part of the code as in the original code because the question is mostly about how static classes and members work, not about the file handling. I wanted to make only the relevant changes to the code and leave the rest unchanged so that it doesn't confuse the matter, and making both calls doesn't cause any problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make them static. Just move the initialization code from field-initializers to the constructor. And don't forget to add a `Dispose` method that disposes them.

Comment: I did put a Dispose, right inside the OnStop() method. It's purpose is to lock the file while the program is running.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a static field, just move the initialization to your constructor:

```
private FileStream fs;
private StreamWriter sw;

public MyClass()
{
    fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
    sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
}
```

To make sure, your `OnStop()` method is really called and the stream is disposed, implement `IDisposable` in your class and call `OnStop()` at the end of your `Dispose()` method.

Comment: It prompts the error "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct"

Comment: replace "MyClass" with the name of your class... MyClass() should be your constructor.