# Keeping an open StreamWriter as Class Field

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, streamwriter

I was trying to write a class that would keep an open `StreamWriter` until the instantiated object was destroyed -- this is to avoid the normal `using` idiom, because it's important that outside sources do not edit the file while the program is running (hence `FileShare.Read`).

Once instantiated, the file is created successfully via the constructor.  Calls to the `Write` method do not actually write anything and throw no exceptions.  Once the object is destroyed, the destructor throws an exception on the `sw.Close()` of `Cannot access a closed file.`, even though the `BaseStream` isn't `null`.  I'm not sure I understand the reasoning for that.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105545/initializing-filestream-and-streamwriter-fields-in-a-service-class) follows somewhat similar approach, but in some other type of class.  So I thought this approach should have worked, but wasn't able to determine why it isn't.

```
class SchemaWriter
{
    private StreamWriter sw;
    private string path;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object to handle writing Schema.ini information
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Path">Path to place Schema.ini file in</param>
    public SchemaWriter(string Path)
    {
        path = Path;
        sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path + "Schema.ini", FileMode.Create,
                              FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes Schema information about the supplied file name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FileName">Name of file to write the Schema info about</param>
    public void Write(string FileName)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format(@"[{0}]", FileName));
        sw.WriteLine(@"Format=TabDelimited");
        sw.WriteLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes StreamWriter, deletes ini file
    /// </summary>
    ~SchemaWriter()
    {
        if(sw.BaseStream != null)
            sw.Close();
        File.Delete(path + @"Schema.ini");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC has already claimed it (and disposed of it).
The only thing you should do is to implement `IDisposable`. Do the following:

```
class SchemaWriter : IDisposable
{
    private StreamWriter sw;

    public void Dispose()
    {
       sw.Dispose();
    }

    ...
}
```

You can now use your object with:

```
using(var writer = new SchemaWriter())
{
}
```

This will close your `StreamWriter` immediately when you are done with the object. And if you don't use the `using` the GC will collect the `StreamWriter` for you when it feels like it.

Comment: Implementing the `IDisposable` interface seemed to work great.  I had to, in addition to this, add a `sw.Flush()` in my `Write` method as sircodesalot pointed out.

Comment: @user17753 Calling `sw.Dispose()` will also flush the writer. But if you need the data to be in the file directly when you call write than you need to flush it directly, if not I would however not recommend to do it there.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons you use should a `using` block is that `StreamReaders`/`Writers` are buffered so that they don't have to reaccess the hard drive for every byte written. This means that you may not see your data actually output to the disk until you call `StreamWriter.Flush`.

I would still reccomend using the `using` blocks, but just use the 'leave open' override. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853.aspx

Comment: I see what you're saying about `Flush`, they must've added that `true` option to the `StreamWriter` constructor in `.net-4.5` as I don't see it in `.net-4.0`.